# I am able to do install packages as root but not as a user. Getting error like "could not resolve in.ubuntu.archieve.com"

Tags: apt, permissions

I am able to do install packages as root but not as a non-root user. Getting error like "could not resolve in.ubuntu.archieve.com"

Non-root User has sudo access.

All my /etc/resolv.conf files are updated fine, if not it should not work for root user too right?

Comment: I hope you are using `sudo <install command>`.

Comment: Check the spelling.. you've made a typo at least in your question...

Comment: Yes, i am using sudo apt-get 'command'

Comment: @guiverc, yeah sorry for the typo

Comment: Did you mistype `archive` in `in.ubuntu.archieve.com` in question or is it really what you see in error messages?

Comment: If it was a 'typo' we currently don't know if it was a typo on your machine, or just the question. I assume IF it was just the question, you'd have edited the question and corrected the typo (*you can edit your own questions*) so it still reads like a typo on your machine which you need to fix (the issue stands out as typos usually aren't repeated where your error appears twice)..

Answer (score 0):

What are your permissions?

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
```

Other users must have **read** permission.
Example:

```
-rw-r--r--.
```

Comment: Yes, others have read permission

Comment: root@grc-bngvdipl001:~# ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 211 Jan 21 11:46 /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Can you test the internet connection as a normal user? ping 8.8.8.8 ?